# Import selenium error on hostmonster shared linux server

Tags: php, python, selenium, hostmonster

I have created a python script that uses selenium to automate an online task. The script works perfect on my local machine (windows 7) and gives the output i am looking for. I am now trying to get it up and running from PHP on my hostmonster shared server which is running linux and having no luck.

I have installed this version of selenium on both my win7 comp and the server:  pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
Python version: 2.7.5
The script i wrote gets the following error at "import selenium":ImportError: No module named selenium

When i log into the server through ssh shell, i can type in "import selenium" and receive no errors. I can also type in "from selenium import webdriver" in the ssh shell and receive no errors.
Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to start your script in the server?

Comment: I am running it from a php script. If i comment out or remove all the selenium lines the script runs. I'm also using BeautifulSoup which imports fine aswell as mechanize.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "stops running"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the output of the error in my php script from the python script. So I have been using trial and error and just commenting out the lines I think are creating issues. If I comment out all the selenium lines, the script runs. If i uncomment  the "import selenium" line. The script fails to return output into a variable of my php script.

Comment: more information/things i have tried: deleting selenium.pyc file, changing selenium egg folder name to "selenium"

Comment: I initially used this command from ssh shell to install selenium:"python setup.py install".  I just found a forum post that said to remove all the selenium folders from the python Lib file and then reinstall using pip. I installed pip and then used the command "pip install -U selenium" to install selenium, which was successful.  However, the same issue remains.

Comment: I have now upgrade my python version to 2.7.5 with hostmonsters handy upgrade instructions located here. https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/python-install   - I edited the commands to download and install version 2.7.5.  Still the same issue remains. Does anyone know how to get the traceback from the python script into a php variable so I can view it.

Comment: are you using `exec` to run the python program?

Comment: Yes I am using: `exec("python <file location of python script is here>", $output, $result);`

Comment: that gives you the output of the python program in `$output`, and the return code in `$result`, what are those?

Comment: $output is an array that produces this - Array ( [0] => Traceback (most recent call last): [1] => File "<file location is here>", line 11, in [2] => import selenium [3] => ImportError: No module named selenium )                           and $result produces the number "1". If i remove the "import selenium" line and run the script, $result produces a "0".

Comment: can you check the output of `python -c "import sys;print sys.path"` when run through php and manually?

Comment: The output was too long to enter into a comment so I added it as an answer below. As for php how do I go about running that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I used the following command to install selenium outside of the python folder.
`easy_install --prefix=$HOME/.local/ selenium`
I also added these lines at the bottom of my .bashrc file located in my home directory
`export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

when i enter
 `import sys`
and then
`print sys.path`
into ssh shell I receive the following:
 `['', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/html2text-3.200.3-py2.7.egg', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python27.zip', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home2/klickste/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`